# Navigate OO JS code

Tags: javascript, vim, netbeans, textmate, aptana

I do a lot of JavaScript editing, and now with Node becoming a popular server-side scripting language I can see myself using even more JS than ever. The problem I have is finding a way to navigate large amounts of Object Oriented JavaScript code.

**TextMate** has a way to view "symbols" but it's a flat structure that I don't find very useful. **Vim** has TagList but I can't seem to get it to work very well with JS. **Sublime Text** can search through functions very well, but again, it's a flat list.

**BBEdit** lists functions hierarchically, which is awesome, but the list is usually really long since you cannot collapse/fold the list.

**Aptana** and **NetBeans** have a nice outline viewer, which are about as close to perfect as I've been able to find: Hierarchical layout, search filter, folding, sorting options, etc.. My only problem with both is that they're a bit slow (at least to load), and they only show functions within an open file (not within a project).

My ideal solution would be some kind of standalone app that could be opened with a hot key. You could then see a list of all your functions inside all your files (in a project), filter the list using a search string, and then when you find the function you're after open it in your favorite editor.

**In other words, I'd like to navigate by objects rather than file structure.** Is this possible?

I use a Mac primarily, but I'd also be interested in hearing about solutions for Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: user long and descriptive names for javascript variables, functions etc. That way there is more chance that they will be unique. Having a load() function on every class makes it really hard to figure out which load is being called. Consider loadParty() loadPerson()

Answer (score 1):

You want Mozilla's [jsctags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs), built expressly for this purpose. You can use it with (e.g.) [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) or [taglist-plus](http://discontinuously.com/2011/03/vim-support-javascript-taglist-plus/).

Comment: From the screenshoots, it looks like Tagbar and jsctags would be perfect. But, for some reason I can't get jsctags working with Tagbar. Thanks for the info, though. I'll have to see if I can get it working proper.

Answer (score 1):

You could check WebStorm ( http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ ) - I've switched to it few months ago, and it's definitely the best IDE for JS right now. It has a nice outline too, understands JS pretty well, and is fast.

Comment: It is kind of quick, but coming from VIM and TextMate, it's just way too slow. Thanks though, I'll play with WebStorm a bit more. Looks pretty interesting.

Comment: yeah I'm know what you mean. I'm using VIM too wherever I can, but I think in bigger projects it's reasonable to trade some speed for other features. btw., there's also a 'IdeaVIM' plugin for WebStorm: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?webide&id=164

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the plug, but I'm the author of [Tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) and thought it would be helpful to mention that I just added support for jsctags (and potentially other compatible programs) to it. If jsctags is in your $PATH it should just work out-of-the-box, otherwise the documentation should provide you with all needed information. Let me know if you find any problems!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, opening a JS file with "JavaScript Editor" gives you a rather nice outline which can be navigated with the keyboard: the arrows do what the arrows normally do and you can hit `a` to go to the next member starting with `a`.

The whole thing is quite slow on my own (old) G5 but it's OK on the MacPro I have at work.